# What could a species with levitating hands do that a normal species couldn't?

Tags: biology, creature-design

This species are like humans otherwise but with the 3 other differences of grey skin, 5 figures  + thumb rather than 4 figures + thumb, & being able to regularly engage in cannibalism without getting a prion disease. They don't have shoulders or shoulder muscles. Their hands are not physically attached in any way. Their legs & head are still attached normally. The hands cannot be moved more than 1.25m from their body. Attempting to move the hands further than 2 meters from the body by force results in a *very not good*. The technology level is near future. They have there own society that doesn't like interacting with normal humans. But humans are still present. They live in an environment that is mostly absent of plant life.

What would this species levitating hands allow them to do that a species with arms couldn't?

Comment: By floating do you meaning hanging down like sacks of dead meat?

Comment: @SteroidSandwich don't question how their hands float

Comment: @OT-64 SKOT I don't want to be nit picky but you should replace the word "float" with "levitating". Otherwise it might give the idea of balloon hands.

Comment: Scratch that itch that's just out of reach on your back.

Comment: Does there need to be  an open path between the hands and the body, or could a member  of this species put a hand  in a jar, seal the jar, and still be able to use the hand?

Comment: @notovny they could do that, the only real limitation is that how far away they can move their hand

Comment: "You are stealing from me, you damned pickpocket!" - "Who, me? It's not my hand!" - "Whose hand is this? Anybody?"

Comment: how much weight the hand can lift an object?

Comment: @LiJun about as much as a normal human, how much can be lifted can be improved using methods a human could

Comment: what about pulling and pushing ?

Comment: @LiJun about as much as a human, how much can be pushed or pulled can be improved using methods a human could

Answer (score 1):

**Quite a lot of stuff**

- Scratch your own back
- Pick that TV remote that's just too far away
- Taking multitasking in a kitchen to another level
- Actually sitting 1.5m away from a laptop screen (good for eyes)
- Playing Basketball, Cricket and Baseball will get tricky.
- & much much more.

**Some Serious stuff**

- If they hunt for cannibalism, then placing traps at some odd angles.
- Can use a bigger Bow and Arrow, as a longbow can give more power to the arrow.
- Similarly bigger (but lightweight) slingshots, guns, and rifles.
- Holding a prisoner will be much easier, just put his arms in a small cage, and he can't run.
- Torturing someone will be easy.

Comment: It'll be much easier to reach things under the sofa, or through other tight gaps. Also I think you mean "Hands" not "Arms" in the 4th serious bullet. And can you elaborate on the Torturing point? I don't see how that one works.

Comment: @Jontia tie them to a chair and go "you can answer our questions or we can place this box with your hands inside 2 meters away. Which will it be?"

Comment: bow not necessarily need to be big to give more power, it just need to be rigid, but still... OP dont mention how strong the hands pull or lift at the moment though.